# Are Windows applications written in Kotlin possible to be debugged using a debugger tool?

Tags: windows, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I was able to make a Kotlin multiplatform application using IntelliJ IDE.

There are 4 platforms: Android, IOS, Windows, MacOS

While I'm able to run and debug application Android package, I can't find any way of running and debugging Windows application package.

I can only build and produce an executable file from the gradle build but for debugging purposes, I can't find a way of making a debugger work for IntelliJ.

Any suggestions?